# Poincaré Dulac example of normal form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

I'd like to find a normal form for the system

$\dot{x}_1$ = $a_1 x_2 x_4 + a_2 x_3 x_4$

$\dot{x}_2$ = $a_2 x_2 x_4 + a_3 x_3 x_4$

$\dot{x}_3$ = $a_3 x_2 x_3 + a_5 x_2 x_4$

$\dot{x}_4 = 0$

that is, with $x_4$ unknown constant. I'd like to understand if a change of variables

$\mathbf{z} = \phi(\mathbf{x})$

such that the system becomes

$\dot{\mathbf{z}}  = \widehat{A} \mathbf{z}$

is possible.

If I'm not mistaken, the Poincaré-Dulac theorem should provide conditions for it.

The question is: does this form exist? and how can I get it?